# Question to be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

A helpful flag was raised by a user that lacks the reputation to vote to reopen on this post. Rather than delay a reopen, I’m posting in case others feel the same.

[How to get iphone message history on PC?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/394296/how-to-get-iphone-message-history-on-pc)

Without an edit, it seems like a good candidate to keep closed, but I’m open to other readings on it. Heck, the new question might be better to keep and we close the old “can I get free tools” in favor of a question that’s not about price and solely about function.

No answers are needed unless you have questions on process or want advice before editing to voting.

Would anyone be willing to help with an edit or vote if they feel this is not a duplicate or that the close is in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like we’ll maintain the current status. We can always act later if needed.